# How to set PATH to run programs outside of default path?

Tags: path, environment-variables, tcsh, csh

I'm working on a project on my school's linux servers. I have a program deep in a directory, we'll say it's /afs/csic.umd.edu/class/cmsc311/0101/cs311xxx/class/cmsc311/0101/cs311xxx/datalab-handout/datalab-handout

What do I setenv the PATH variable to so that I can run the program in that directory? It is currently set to /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin so obviously I want to add to the end of that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

csh/tcsh you say?

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:/my/additional/path
```

*Update: Fixed my error of forgetting to escape the colon. Thanks Dennis.*

Comment: I did so, specifically  setenv PATH $PATH:/afs/csic.umd.edu/class/cmsc311/0101/cs311055/class/cmsc311/0101/cs311055/datalab-handout/datalab-handout  but I keep getting the error Bad : modifier in $ (/).

Comment: @Rowhawn: You need to escape the colon: `setenv PATH $PATH\:/more/dirs` or use braces around the variable: `setenv PATH ${PATH}:/more/dirs`